# Where should I store sensitive variables? 

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

This is my first time working on a secure website.  It's for a pet project I have.

For security purposes, where is it best to store information like SQL connection strings, database encryption keys, etc?  Is it better to use web.config, store them in a class that accesses a database (like dataBaseHelper.cs or something), or somewhere else?

I intend to obtain an SSL cert as well.  When communicating with the database, should I always use the secure connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an article that will help solve the problem about whether or not this can be done on a server hosting my site.  Just googled based off the answers you guys gave above.  Worked pretty well.

http://sharpertutorials.com/webconfig-encryption/

Thanks for the help and direction.

Answer (score 10):

Check [Encrypting sections of config files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtkwfdky.aspx) section on MSDN.

Comment: Good advice, an encrypted section of a config file was what I would recommend also.

Comment: That looks exactly like what I was looking for.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the app, it's generally best-practice to use a KMS to store encryption keys. If a KMS is not available because of budget constraints or whatever, Key Containers are the next best option. Once your key is protected you can store variables either in encrypted sections of the config file as suggested, or as encrypted byte arrays in the assembly itself.

Comment: After reviewing that suggestion, I'm assuming I'd need to get a bit of information from the service that is hosting my site.  Do you know if that information is something they freely give to the average customer?  Seems like sensitive info.

Comment: One wouldn't generally keep a KMS in a DMZ, so depending on your hosting provider, they may or may not be able to accommodate. They should be able to tell you whether they support network segmentation and/or LAN-to-LAN VPNs for you to house a KMS within a private network.